# GASでスプレッドシートからSQLクエリを取得し、そのクエリのパラメータを書き換える方法

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-bigquery

掲題の件について方法がわからず、困っております。

スプレッドシートに記載したクエリをGASで取得し、GASからBigQueryにクエリを投げるコードを書いています。
ここで、所定のパラメータを取得したクエリに代入したいのですが、うまくいきません。
GASコード内にベタ打ちするとうまくいくのですが...

（クエリ ベタ打ちの例）
`var query="SELECT * FROM hoge WHERE DAYS BETWEEN '${start}' AND '${end}'"`

（クエリ SSから取得の例）
`var query=sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()`

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらヒントいただけますと幸いです。